# Can I override or add-to the default WinJS win-template class output?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, controltemplate

Here is my template:

```
<!-- TEMPLATE -->
<div id="templateDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="tile" data-win-bind="textContent: QuestionText"></div>
</div>
```

My output is this:

```
<div id="itemsControl" data-win-control="Samples.ItemsControl">
    <div class="win-template">
        <div class="tile" data-win-bind="textContent: QuestionText">Sample Data 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="win-template">
        <div class="tile" data-win-bind="textContent: QuestionText">Sample Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="win-template">
        <div class="tile" data-win-bind="textContent: QuestionText">Sample Data 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="win-template">
        <div class="tile" data-win-bind="textContent: QuestionText">Sample Data 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to override class="**win-template**" or add to the class attribute in the output.  I have tried to put class="sample-class" in the templateDiv without luck. It seems to override everything I try.

Answer (score 0):

The win-template class is just a class that the WinJS.Binding.Template control adds to each rendering of a template to mark them as such. The WinJS stylesheets don't actually define any styles for win-template, so you're free to assign any styles you want, i.e.

```
#itemsControl .win-template {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Alternately, start your template with another  that is the container for the rest of the template, and the Template control won't do anything to it.

Comment: Yes, I have done that (for now). But I wanted to know if the .win-template can be overridden or permanently set.  I guess the answer is "no", just use what is there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "permanently set" or overridden. The only way that would happen is by altering the WinJS stylesheets, which you can't do anyway as it would affect other apps. Changing it in your own CSS that's loaded after WinJS is the way to do the override.